# Angular 2 unit tests in Karma/Jasmine reporting true as false

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've written a unit test in an Angular 2 app using Jasmine. I had some issues at first so boiled down the test to a simple "true == false", which still passes the test!

My test preparation is as follows

```
let component: HubDetailComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<HubDetailComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [HubDetailComponent],
    imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), FormsModule],
    providers: [
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: Observable.of({ id: 1 }) } },
      { provide: HubService, useClass: MockHubService }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HubDetailComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

And the passing test is

```
it('should ... ', async () => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    console.log("stable!"); // this gets logged

    expect(true).toBe(false); // passes!
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the `async/await` syntax with Angular's lame `async` test helper wrapper. Try `async(() => ...`

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I really have to wonder about some of these Angular APIs though. They seem to aim for the pit of failure instead of the pit of success.